# nodejs return response body in request module

Tags: node.js, callback, request

NodeJS. I have a function named 'createDynamicLink' and I want this function to return the response body that returned in request object.

```
function createDynamicLink(){
   .
   .
   .
   .

  request({
    url: dynamicLinksApi,
    method: "POST",
    json: true,
    body: body,
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log("link: " + response.body.shortLink);
    return response.body.shortLink; // <---- I want this value be // returned when I call the createDynamicLink function
  });
}

var dynamicLink = createDynamicLink(); 
console.log(dynamicLink)  // <----- This writes 'undefined' to // console screen
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and have the code better formatted? There a code feature in the editor to do that. I tried copying and pasting your code on my IDE, but as it's just pieces of the code, it won't properly format it.

Comment: Sorry, I did the fixes